# Why does static electricity attract water, but magnetic field applies a mutual repulsive force?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, water

Water is diamagnetic because when oxygen bonds to two hydrogens all electrons are paired off with their magnetic spins cancelling each other out. Does not matter whether the south or north pole is used, water will be repelled.  On the other hand, it is also polarized and will be attracted by static electricity. I guess my confusion is how can water be electric balanced in terms of spins but unbalanced in terms of charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Water being diamagnetic, it excludes magnetic field (weakly).   This makes 
repulsion according to the absolute value of the  magnetic field (and field direction is unimportant).   Water is also ionic (weakly conductive),
so excludes electric field.   That exclusion, however, is a result of
migration of charges to the surface of the water, positive charge
being built up on parts of the water surface where electric field
lines are out of the water surface, and negative charge where electric
field lines are INTO the water surface.  Direction is important.

Both those surface charge concentrations put attracted charge near
the field source (where intensity is greatest), and are attractive.
That might mean (if one surface has more field than the opposite) a net
attractive force, or it might just turn a spherical water droplet
into a slightly elongated shape, without any net force.

Any material that can generate a small electric polarization will
similarly be attracted by a strong-from-one-side electric field; that's how static
electricity can pick up specks of pepper, for instance.